# Encoding error with CSV file not allowing me to vectorize the data

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, countvectorizer

I have a .csv file that has the format below:
[image]

[image]

I am using pandas to read it and then encoding it using utf-8 but it looks like pandas isn't splitting the columns "Sentence" and "Label" properly
[image]

I am then vectorizing it using CountVectorizer and then turning it into an array before doing the train-test split for machine learning modeling."
[image]

However I am getting an error just saying 'Sentence' when I try to "fit_transform"
[image]

I think the error is coming up since there is no column 'Sentence', it is still viewing it as "Sentence,Label'. Does anyone know if it's a pandas issue or an encoding issue?

Comment: Can you show the code where you read the csv file?

Comment: sure, just added @jakub

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. (Pictures of code are generally unwelcome).